# Gremlin Console + Neo4j 3.3.0 CE

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

I need to connect with gremlin to my Neo4j 3.3.0 CE instance.

On my gremlin console I had executed this command:

```
gremlin> :install org.apache.tinkerpop neo4j-gremlin 3.3.0
```

to install the necessary plugin.

Trying to open the graphdb with this:

```
gremlin> graph = Neo4jGraph.open("/home/user/neo4j-community-3.3.0/data/databases/graph.db")
```

I have this error:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradeNotAllowedByConfigurationException: Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version. To enable automatic upgrade, please set configuration parameter "allow_store_upgrade=true"
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.ConfigMapUpgradeConfiguration.checkConfigurationAllowsAutomaticUpgrade(ConfigMapUpgradeConfiguration.java:39)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.migrateIfNeeded(StoreUpgrader.java:135)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.upgradeStore(NeoStoreDataSource.java:636)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:527)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
```

I have Neo4J 3.3.0 and I install the 3.3.0 neo4j-gremlin plugin. Which version of the plugin I must install to connect to my 3.3.0 neo4j instance?

I must upgrade the store?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The last released version of the tinkerpop (3.3.0) support is for Neo4j 3.2.3, so it won't work with a newer store. (The version numbers can be misleading)

You can try to build the 3.3 branch of https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-tinkerpop-api-impl/tree/3.3 locally and use that resulting jar.